# Ensuring a Gradle task is executed after another task

Tags: heroku, gradle

I have the following issue with my gradle build: Heroku guarantees to execute the `stage` task (see below) but I need a custom `cleanUp` task (see below) to be executed just after the `stage` task.

I am not sure how to achieve this... Can anyone please help?

```
task cleanUp(type: Delete) {
   delete 'bignibou-server/build/install'
}

//Executed/invoked by Heroku
task stage(dependsOn: [':bignibou-server:bootRepackage', ':bignibou-server:installDist'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically task dependencies are configured with `dependsOn` and `mustRunAfter`, but it seems that what you need can be done with simple `doLast`:

```
stage.doLast {
   project.file('bignibou-server/build/install').deleteDir()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can declare a task which must always be executed after another task (regardless whether the task succeeded or not):

```
stage.finalizedBy "someOtherTask" //someOther task will always be executed after "stage"
```